# Редирект каталога на страницу .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Не получается в .htaccess сделать 301 редирект следующего типа: 
все страницы каталога `site.ru/catalog/` должны перенаправляться на страницу `site.ru/page.php`.

Причем не только страницы, лежащие непосредственно в /catalog/, но и в подкаталогах, то есть, например

`site.ru/catalog/podcatalog/` → `site.ru/page.php`
`site.ru/catalog/podcatalog/page1.php` → `site.ru/page.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/
RewriteRule .+ /page.php
```

Все адреса, начинающиеся с `/catalog/` будут перенаправлены на `/page.php`.

Проверить можно здесь: [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be)

---

**updated:**

Я забыл упомянуть флаги, о которых сказал [@Andrey -hidden-](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200629/andrey-hidden) в своем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576010/13336).

Учитывая ваш комментарий, верный вариант такой:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /catalog/
RewriteRule .+ /page.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: А если /catalog/ не первый подкаталог, то есть site.ru/smth/catalog/ то как сделать?

Comment: Разобрался, нужно ^ убрать.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/
RewriteRule .+ /page.php [L,R=301]
```

`L` - не проводить более никаких преобразованй адреса

`R=301` - вернуть код 301

Answer (score 0):

/wp-admin/fi000675.php-action=image?id=ahr0cdovl3d3dy5wcm9mzxnzyxlzlmnvbs93cc1jb250zw50l3vwbg9hzhmvmjaxmc8wms9eaxnzzxj0yxrpb24tbwv0ag9kb2xvz3ktznjlzs1zyw1wbguuanbn
при редиректе на главную, например, оставляет ?id= и все за ним

Comment: Отформатируйте пожалуйста сообщение.